# C# Time calculation confusion :: TimeSpan.FromHours(12) will check if its more than 12 hrs

Tags: c#

Will `TimeSpan.FromHours` check if the time is more than 12 hours 0 minutes and 0 seconds?

Or is it ONLY going to check if the number is more than 12 or not, i.e. ONLY hours? If yes, how do you check if it's not even a second more than 12 hours?

Comment: What prevented you from spending a minute to write 3 lines of code and check it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FromHours` method doesn't compare times, it creates a new `TimeSpan` value. `TimeSpan.FromHours(12)` creates a `TimeSpan` with the value `12:00:00.00000`.

You can use it to compare it with a `TimeSpan` value:

```
if (someTimeSpan > TimeSpan.FromHours(12)) ...
```

This will not enter the block if `someTimeSpan` is `12:00:00.00000` but it will if it's `12:00:00.00001` or more.

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeSpan.FromHours(x) - TimeSpan.FromHours(12) <= TimeSpan.Zero
```

Or, of course, bypass the TimeSpan entirely before calling `FromHours`:

```
if (x - 12 <= 0) return TimeSpan.FromHours(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TimeSpan` class represents a span of time, `TimeSpan.FromHours(12)` is a time span of 12 hours. Maybe you confused it with the `DateTime` class?